# Is there a good reason that a form tag should not exist in the head tag?

Tags: html

Is there a good reason that a form tag should not exist in the head tag?

I was looking at this http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-form-element
but I could not find anything related to this question.

This works for me:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a good reason the form tag *should* exist in the head tag?

Comment: I think he wants to put the form tag there because the asp's script manager adds some scripts where it is located, and he wants those scripts located inside the head tag... I know it because I tried to do exactly that 3 years ago :P, so Soenhay, you should put it inside the body tag a have a happy life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/saved/2014 in a browser other than IE (which has a very strange bug here),  you will see that your form element is not in fact inside the head element. When the parser sees the `<form>` tag, it automatically closes the `<head>` element, creates the `<body>` element and puts the `<form>` element and all subsequent elements inside that `<body>` element.

Because this behaviour is necessary for backward compatibility with existing web pages, the spec can't be changed to allow `<form>` elements in head, even if there were a good use case for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

HTML intended for display belongs in the `<body>` tag.

There are some browsers that will still display some tags that are put in the `<head>` tag, but that is not where it belongs and you are asking for interoperability problems if you put it there.

In the spec link that you referenced, it says that `<form>` tags go where `flow content` is expected.  If you click on `flow content`, it refers to elements used in the body of documents.  The body is what is in the `<body>` tag.